# Create a sorted array out of 2 arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are 2 arrays given for ex.
A = [20,4,21,6,3]
B = [748,32,48,92,23......]

assuming B is very large and can hold all the elements of array A.

Find the way in which array B is in (containing all the elements of array A as well)  sorted order.

Design an algorithm in the most efficient way.

Comment: is there a way to do it in O(n)????....something which i am looking for

Comment: I don't understand the following sentence: "Find the way in which array B is in sorted order". 
Do you mean that you want to sort both arrays? - Given that you don't know any limitations on the integers range, it can be done at O(nlogn) [and not better than that...].

Comment: @Anna yes it can be done faster than `O(n lg n)`, if it's integer sorting.

Comment: @notnoop, it isn't O(nglogn). If you use the integer range (say, 64 bit), then the complexity of radix sort would be O(64*n), where 64 >= log(n) [as there are 2^64 integers in that range.]

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like merge sort algorithm. You will find tons of examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). You can then modify to suit.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your array is integer array, you can use [Radix sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to sort `B` in linear time, `O(n)`.  Wikipedia has a nice write-up and sample python code.

Radix sort is linear with respect to the number of elements.  While it also has a dependence on the size of the array, you take it as a constant; just like you take the comparison operator to be constant as well.  When sorting bignum for instance, the comparison operator would also depend on the integer size!

Comment: @notnoop, this is not O(n), and most chances are that regular (merge sort, heap sort, or others would run faster).

Comment: @Anno, note my update.  Also, for algorithmic homework, it's the asymptotic behavior is what matters, not the actual runtime execution.

Comment: @notnoop, when counting asymptotic behavior, you get O(nlogn).
In the general case, an integer (in the mathematical sense) can have any number of digits, and therefore, radix sort can be of a larger complexity than O(nlogn) [since it is O(kn), k >> logn].
In the case of an integer, a number can have up to 2^64 different values (therefore, n < 2^64). The maximal number of digits in a number is k=log(2^64)=64. The radix sort complexity is O(kn), but k > logn !
I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: @Anna, but my claim is that if we are considering bignum then similarly a comparison sort would cost `O(k) * O( n lg n )` when taking into account the comparison cost.  So it's unfair to compare `O(kn)` to `O(n lg n)` when you account for k in terms of size in one but its affect in comparision cost in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like homework. Basically, write into array B starting from the end, keeping track of the place you are reading from in both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it out :

1. Merge the array A into B .
2. Use quick sort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before adding elements from A to B check if by doing that if you exceed the size of the array, if not Merge A into B
2. Then do a quick sort,

But if you just want to merge both arrays into a new arrays where new array has the combine length of both. Here is a jump start for you, try if you can go forward from here...

```
public double[] combineArrays(double[] first, double[] second) {

    int totalLenth = first.length + second.length;
    double[] newDoubles = new double[totalLenth];
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        newDoubles[i] = first[i];
    }

    for (int j = first.length; j < newDoubles.length; j++) {
        newDoubles[j] = second[j - first.length];
    }
    return newDoubles;
}
```

Hope this helps, Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify an insertion sort idea:

0) do all necessary tests: if arrays are null, if bigger array has enough space

1) add small array at the end of the big array

2) do normal insertion sort, but start it at the beginning of the small array

- here if you do quick_sort or some other "quickiest" O(n*log_n) sort, the problem is that you are not using the fact, that both array are sorted. With the insertion sort you are using the fact, that array B is sorted (but not the fact that A is sorted, so maybe we should develop the idea and modify insertion sort to use that fact as well).